# GXT Grid filtering a store

Tags: java, grid, logic, gxt, gxt-charts

I understand that in GXT 3.0 grids are pulling their data from a store (in my case a list store). I am trying to implement a search function to help filter through some of the results in the grid dynamically. However, I am having trouble determining the best method to do this. I have considered doing this server side by modifying the source file..but ultimately I just want to toggle the displaying of a row if it doesn't contain a desired string. Any suggestions for how to best approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using store filter to toggle displaying row that contains the string you desired. Here is the example code:

```
ListStore<YourModelData> listStore = new ListStore<YourModelData>(yourPropertiesObject.key());
StoreFilter<YourModelData> sf = new StoreFilter<YourModelData>() {
    @Override
    public boolean select(Store<YourModelData> store, YourModelData parent,
            YourModelData item) {
        return item.contains("some-string");
    }
};
listStore.addFilter(sf);
```